# How to manage dynamic routing and static pages

Tags: laravel

We build ecommerce and we need to have static rotes for pages like:

- About us
- Home
- Contact

**For static pages links need to looks like this:**

`www.example.com/home  www.example.com/contact`

On the other hand, we have product categories, subcategories and products whose servant is located in the database. Each category and product contains the full path in the slug table, for example:

DB Slug: `/car/bmw/parts/<product>`

And link need to looks like this:
`www.example.com/car/bmw/parts/<product>`

It is clear to us that there is a conflict here, how to determine whether it is a static side or a dynamic side.
Paths must be exactly like this without adding `/category` or `/product` or `/page/{page}`. This is what our client requires

For categories, subcategories and products, we achieved a result, but we have a problem with static pages that the system treats as a category or product.

**Route:**

```
// Route for category, sub-cat and products

Route::group(['namespace' => 'fronted', 'middleware' =>'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/{categories?}', [FrontedController::class, 'index'])->where('categories', '^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+$')->name('home');
});

// Static pages
// Homepage
Route::get('/', [HomePageController::class, '__invoke'])->name('home');

// About us
Route::get('/about-us', [AboutUsPageController::class, '__invoke'])->name('about-us');

// Shop / Products
Route::get('/products', [ShopPageController::class, '__invoke'])->name('shop');

// Blog
Route::get('/blog', [BlogPageController::class, '__invoke'])->name('blog');

// Contact
Route::get('/contact', [ContactPageController::class, '__invoke'])->name('contact');
```

**Method**

```
public function index($categories= null)
{
    $menu_items = Category::where('parent_id', null)->where('name', '!=', 'Root')->get();

    // get categories in array
    $cats = explode('/', $categories);

    // make array to string used for slug
    $cat_slug = implode('/', $cats);

    // remove last url param. Used when you route only category without post
    array_pop($cats);

    // Its simple alias (name convention)
    $post_slug = $cat_slug;

    // No url params provided? Show home page

    if(!$categories) {
        return view('ecommerce::fronted.default.homepage',[
            'menu_items' => $menu_items,
        ]);
    }
    // Category param exist

    else if($categories) {

        // Get category based on url slug
        $category = Category::where('slug', $cat_slug)->with('children')->first();

        // Here we must determine if category or post. If category not found we load post.

        // Category does not exist! Load product
        if(!$category) {
            $product = Product::where('slug', $post_slug)->first();

            return view('ecommerce::fronted.default.product',[
                'menu_items' => $menu_items,
                'product' => $product
            ]);            }
        // Category founded load it and their childs
        else {
            $products = $category->products;
            return view('ecommerce::fronted.default.category',[
                'menu_items' => $menu_items,
                'products' => $products,
                'category' => $category
            ]);
        }

    }
    // Nothing founded! Show 404
    else {
        abort('404');
    }

}
```

With this code we successfully route product categories, subcategories and products but we have problem when we call page like `/about-us`, `/contact`, `/blog`. He tries to find a category.

Is there a way to separate this?

Comment: Just move static routes to the top of api.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel the routes are loaded by its order in your routes file, meaning - the first matched route will be the one that laravel use.

You can just add the static routes before the dynamic ones and it should solve it.